# what does wait visibility method mean in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to know what this method means: root.wait_visibility(root),
In the tikinter app. The intention is to change the visibility of the window. I recently switched from windos to linux and I'm having difficulties in the differences between operating systems, because in windows this same function is different.
code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()

root.geometry("600x400+400+200")

root.title('My GUI Application')

**root.wait_visibility(root)**

root.wm_attributes('-alpha',0.50)
```

Comment: `wait_visibility` is rarely used due the fact that it does not work on all platforms. The intention of it was to wait until the window is visible. You could use a binding for `<Map>` instead.

Comment: thanks for the feedback . is it like waiting for the window to be visible to make the change?

Comment: Yes, it waits until your window is mapped and continues with your code block if the condition is met.

Comment: There is a really good description of the problem of visibility in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48301923/7432